# Custom Exception with WCF

Tags: wcf, exception, custom-exceptions, faultexception

hey i am using Oleg Sych's solution for handling exception via WCF:
[link](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/)

everything works well with Known Exceptions (such as InvalidOperationException and SystemException) but when i am trying to use my own custom exception, it doesnt work and i get the following wcf exception:
"There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)"

this is my custom exception:

```
[KnownType(typeof(SessionExpiredException))]
[global::System.Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class SessionExpiredException : Exception
{
    public SessionExpiredException() { }
    public SessionExpiredException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public SessionExpiredException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected SessionExpiredException(
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
}
```

what am i doing wrong? am i missing an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to model your custom error as an exception, but as a DataContract with DataMembers for the information you intent to return. Then, on the WCF service, just return a FaultException of your type.

This page has a good sample on how to model it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx

Comment: On the other hand, using a `FaultException<TDetail>` gets you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score -1):

```
public SessionExpiredException() { }
    public SessionExpiredException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public SessionExpiredException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected SessionExpiredException(
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
```

**the above solution is WRONG.**